# Inconsistent Integer conversion

Tags: c#

I have a csv file that i am reading in that contains strings like the following: `ab1>aa2`,`cc1>ed2`.

I am using the following code to read it in...

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file));
var line = reader.ReadLine(); // first line parameter
var values = line.Split(',');
```

Assume that `values[0] = "ab1>aa2"` and `values[1] = "cc1>ed2"` from reading the first line.

Now what I have found is that if i try to do

`int num = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);`

I get the typical error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Now on the other hand, if I just assign a random variable a string `string str = "ab1>aa2"` and convert it the same way its works fine.

I have confirmed `value[0]` is `System.String`. and i have tried both `int.Parse` and `TryParse` and they both give the same error.

Anyone experienced this before?

---

Reproducible Example:

To create the spreadsheet, simple open up excel and put in `ab1>aa2`,`cc1>ed2` in the A1 and B1 cell respectively. Save it as `Book1.csv`

```
var reader = new  StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Book1.csv"));
var line = reader.ReadLine(); // first line parameter
var values = line.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(values[0]);

Int32 num = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]); //problem
```

Comment: can you post a reproducable example? I can't reproduce this at the moment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hCx8Bq

Comment: `ab1>aa2` will never be converted or parsed to a int.

Comment: You state `values[1] = "cc1>ed2"` and then you try `int num = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);` - this is not a valid integer, so it would never convert ....

Comment: you need to use `string.Replace()` function to not use the `>` this is so obvious [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_type_conversion.htm) start freshening up on your reading please..

Comment: If you are right about `string str = "ab1>aa2"` and convert it to an integer, what is the resulting value? I'm really curious.

Comment: Apologies, I have done subsetting. Already. To extract the String integers.

Answer (score 2):

this values, `ab1>aa2` and `cc1>ed2`  are not a integers.

you can first validate the data using int.TryParse and if a result is true, tou can instantiate a variable of type integer.